# Scoreboard design using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I m trying to design a score board in following manner:

```
                  0 - 0
               Home - Away
```

Now the issue happening here is the if the length of name of Home team is bigger, it pushing the - further. I want - to be aligned with the - in the score above. my html structure is something like following:

```
      <div className="score">
        <span>0</span>-<span>0</span>
      </div>
      <div className="team">
        <span>{homeName}</span>-<span>{awayName}</span>
      </div>
```

I have tried putting `direction` property to the span to use `rtl`. I also tried providing `text-align` `center` and putting the `position` property as fixed. but it didnt work.  Not sure if I m going right here or not. Any help is appreciated

Comment: why not using a table?

Comment: is there any limit on the characters that could be there in the name of the teams, that need to be displayed on the screen

Comment: Have you heard about [CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)?

Comment: Is CSS Grid supported in IE9 ?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I didnt consider it. Thats a good option I guess.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour is there any option to do this without table ?

Comment: IE9 End of life was 20 months ago. Please stop supporting obsoleted browsers and move on to modern web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add an extra wrapper you can simply use `display:table`

```css
.main {
  display: table;
}

.score,
.team {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
}

span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

span:last-child {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/*the line between scores*/
span:first-child::before {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  right:-2px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="score">
    <span>0</span><span>0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span>Home</span><span>away</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="score">
    <span>0</span><span>0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <span>Home Home Home</span><span>away</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can  I get every thing in the wrapper div aligned in center ? @Temani Afif

Comment: @PranayTripathi add margin:auto to main div ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but you always have number of other ways to style as you need.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="home-screen">
     <p> 0 </p>
     <p> Home </p>
  </div>
  <div> - <div>
  <div class="away-screen">
     <p> 0 </p>
     <p> Away </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```